# How can I run simple http server on my dynamic IP?

Tags: http, ubuntu, command-line, nginx, webserver

Sorry for the language mistakes I've made. I don't have static IP to be accessible from outside world so I want to run a dead simple http server on my dynamic IP which I get from DHCP of my local provider. How can I make it?

I use Ubuntu and similar with nginx. I tried something like this:

```
 ~path/to/index.html$ python -m SimpleHTTPServer 80 #of course nothing
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can,
But you must use a proxy like:

- [DYN DNS](https://account.dyn.com/entrance/%E2%80%8E)
- [NO-IP](https://www.noip.com/)
- etc.

These sites gives you a link static IP and forwards it to your dynamic IP address.
The IP provider needs to be updated with your current IP.

This is done either via a service on your computer, or via your router (if it supports **Dynamic DNS** it).

The conclusion is that your current IP address must somehow be connected to a DNS (like *www.something.org*).

Comment: Great answer) I can't understand why somebody puts a negative on my question..is it so obviously?!